# How can I use T-SQL to find all positions that are not in a list of characters?

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, charindex

I need to find **all** the positions in a string that are not A, G, C, or T (this is genomic data).  I have figured out a way to do this using a loop (see below) but honestly I am not sure if there is a 'smarter' way of doing this.

I am using SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @myTest varchar(max) = 'GGCGATXAATXCCC-GCCT'

DECLARE @pos int =1 

DECLARE @table1 TABLE (position int, DiffValue varchar(1))

WHILE (@pos <= LEN(@myTest)) 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @table1
        SELECT 
            @pos,
            CASE
               WHEN SUBSTRING(@myTest, @pos, 1) NOT IN ('A','G','C','T') 
                  THEN SUBSTRING(@myTest, @pos, 1)                                              
            END
        WHERE 
            SUBSTRING(@myTest, @pos, 1) NOT IN ('A','G','C','T')
    SELECT @pos= @pos + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @table1
```

Results in

```
position    DiffValue
   7            X
   11           X
   15           -
```

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: You could do this with a recursive CTE, or a numbers / tally table with substring, but the best method depends a lot on what kind of data you're going to be using it for.

Comment: Your approach seems good to be honest. Are you concerned about performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just grab a copy of [NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/) and your all set.

```
DECLARE @myTest varchar(max) = 'GGCGATXAATXCCC-GCCT'

SELECT Position, Token 
FROM dbo.ngrams8K(@myTest, 1)
WHERE token NOT LIKE '[AGCT]';
```

Results:

```
Position             Token
-------------------- --------
7                    X
11                   X
15                   -
```

Comment: That N-Grams link is great. Really timely for a project I am working on right now. Thanks for posting.

Comment: Plus1 for the  LIKE '[AGCT]';  ... Never occured to me

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps with an ad-hoc tally table

```
DECLARE @myTest varchar(max) = 'GGCGATXAATXCCC-GCCT'

Select N
      ,S = substring(@myTest,N,1)
 From (Select Top (Len(@myTest)) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2 ) A
 Where substring(@myTest,N,1) not in ('A','G','C','T')
```

Returns

```
N   S
7   X
11  X
15  -
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking something like this as below:

```
DECLARE @myTest varchar(max) = 'GGCGATXAATXCCC-GCCTADASFDASDFXASDASFASDFXASDFASDXASDAS'

;with nums as (
select top(len(@myTest)) RowN = Row_number() over(order by (Select NULL))
    from master..spt_values s1, master..spt_values s2
)
select RowN as Position, DiffValue = SUBSTRING(@myTest,RowN,1) from nums
where SUBSTRING(@myTest,RowN,1) not in ('A','G','C','T')
```

Comment: Interestingly this gives a blank value for position 55 but there are only 54 characters.